# Determine screw size needed from 3MF file(s)

Tags: 3d-models

I have a set of 3MF files to enclose a MacroPad. They have openings for screws that go through top then PCB then into bottom, but I've been unable to figure out the dimensions of the screws needed and Google keeps trying to encourage me to design new screws, but is not returning results for determining the size and length of the screws needed.

I've tried opening the file in a number of applications (OpenSCAD, LibreCAD, etc.) and am unable to figure this out (though this could just be due to inexperience with more than changing the size of existing 3D designs).

Does anyone know if what I'm trying to do is possible, and if so, where can I read about how to do it, or if it's stunningly obvious, what size am I looking for?  If it matters I'm using Linux if it matters.

The MacroPad 3MF files are found [here](http://www.retrobuiltgames.com/app/download/7126357959/3MF+Print+Files+Case+Macro+Keyboard+RC+Ver2.1.rar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meshmixer (free, multi-platform) supports and imports .3MF file format. There's something amiss with the file named Macro Keyboard RC Ver2.1 Top MiniCutout. It appears that the object is created from two improperly overlapped objects that have been merged. The result is a hole that isn't quite a hole:

[image: object corner image with hole]

The other files have holes that appear to be normal. Meshmixer can measure distances but that remains as an exercise to the reader, as it's a royal pain (opinion) to get results with that feature of the program.

[image: "normal" hole corner image]

The above image is of a different part (note image browser in screen cap) with a normal appearing hole.

The curious thing here is that Fusion 360 (free hobbyist license) also supports the file format and when imported, there is no anomaly with the pictured holes. This would imply that Meshmixer doesn't handle the format as correctly as it should. Also the measure feature of F360 is easier to use, resulting in a hole measurement of about 3.2 mm diameter.

The larger hole measures to 5.0 mm diameter.

[image: Fusion 360 image import]

All images created by me via respective programs with files provided by OP.

Comment: Wow, thanks. That''s very thorough and answers my question and then some.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.  If you find my response to be acceptable, please consider to click the check mark.